# using match function to find and replace missing values in a data frame in R (closed)

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
t <- strptime(c("2012-01-01 00:00:00","2012-01-01 01:00:00", "2012-01-01 02:00:00", "2012-01-01 05:00:00", "2012-01-01 06:00:00"), format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");t
d1 <- 2:6
d2 <- 15:11
dfr <- data.frame(t, d1, d2);dfr

                   t d1 d2
 2012-01-01 00:00:00  2 15
 2012-01-01 01:00:00  3 14
 2012-01-01 02:00:00  4 13
 2012-01-01 05:00:00  5 12
 2012-01-01 06:00:00  6 11
```

You can notice that the data from times "2012-01-01 03:00:00" and "2012-01-01 04:00:00" are missing.

To find out the missing data, i first generated a correct time step, then compared it with the "t" column as below.

```
    t1Gen <- strptime("2012-01-01 00:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    t2Gen <- strptime("2012-01-01 06:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    tGen <- seq(t1Gen,t2Gen, 3600);tGen

"2012-01-01 00:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 01:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 02:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 03:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 04:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 05:00:00 CET" 
"2012-01-01 06:00:00 CET"

mdfr <- match(tGen,dfr$t);mdfr
[1]  1  2  3 NA NA  4  5
subfr <- subset(mdfr, is.na(mdfr));subfr
[1] NA NA
```

Using the match function, 2 elements are singled out as missing with "NA". Now my aim is to fill out the two missing rows with "-99" to show that the data is missing, with the resulting dataframe looking like this;

```
                   t d1 d2
 2012-01-01 00:00:00  2 15
 2012-01-01 01:00:00  3 14
 2012-01-01 02:00:00  3 14
 2012-01-01 03:00:00 -99-99
 2012-01-01 04:00:00 -99-99
 2012-01-01 05:00:00  5 12
 2012-01-01 06:00:00  6 11
```

I'm stuck upto this point, any help with this be appreciated.
P.S: Any other code would be welcome as well. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, check out the returned value of `is.na(mdfr)`. The `== TRUE` part is most likely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can `merge` `dfr` and the `tGen` vector (after turning the latter into a data.frame). Specifying `all = TRUE` allows you to fill missing rows with NA.

```
dfrM <- merge(dfr, data.frame(t = tGen), all = TRUE)
```

Then determine which values are missing and replace with `-99`:

```
dfrM[is.na(dfrM)] <- -99

> dfrM
                    t  d1  d2
1 2012-01-01 00:00:00   2  15
2 2012-01-01 01:00:00   3  14
3 2012-01-01 02:00:00   4  13
4 2012-01-01 03:00:00 -99 -99
5 2012-01-01 04:00:00 -99 -99
6 2012-01-01 05:00:00   5  12
7 2012-01-01 06:00:00   6  11
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

```
dfr[subfr, -1] <-  -99   
# assumes that time is your first column, and the rest of the row gets -99
```

---

You can also combine a few lines, if you'd like:

```
dfr[is.na(match(tGen,dfr$t)), -1] <-  -99
```

Comment: I think your code has an error. Seems like all the rows with "NA" are being asssigned with -99, including the date rows.

Comment: yep, you were right.  thanks for catching that, I just fixed it